# require (show rute to my assets) #node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, oracle, require

In this function i need show a file with all my assets similar to XAMPP, "I SAY"
I want get my file, this file have all my .js .html .css .scss, and show all file
in my localhost like a list similar to XAMPP.

```
var http = require('http');
//var assets = require('/assets');

function appServer(request, response){
    //get my assets file and show in localhost:8888
}

http.createServer(appServer).listen(8888);
```

Comment: You aren't clear. Please describe **what** you're trying to do, not **how**. See the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/166899)

Comment: There is no 'assets file' to speak of in a basic node.js program like this.  It would help to understand what 'your assets file' is and why you want to load it and do your 'call to assets file'.  What is 'call to assets file' in this context?

Comment: I want get my file, this file have all my .js .html .css .scss, and show all in my localhost like a list similar to XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

```
function appServer(request, response){    
    fs.readFile('./yourfile.html', function read(err, data) {
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end(data, 'utf-8');
   });
}
```

Comment: If i want to see all my files and no alone text/html ('./yourfile.html')?

Comment: didn't get it... You want to see LIST of NAMES of the files of the directory?